# Best practices and general guidelines

Tags: chapters, document-classes, books, report

I am translating a handwritten notes PDF to LaTeX. Do y'all have any tips on best practices for the same. It has multiple chapters (basically notes for a course) lots of equations and derivations with some Q and A stuff. It has lots of hand drawn diagrams and stuff. So do let me know anything for ex, document class, how to handle figures/equations, file structure etc.

Thanks in advance. I am very comfortable in Latex and would not mind googleing and stuff to get a great result.

Comment: your question is very unclear. Basically it just asks for best practice for writing a generic latex document. I am not sure what answer can be given at this generality

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please be more specific. Try to ask one question at a time. It is hard to come up with an answer for this question given the fact that we don't know the source document nor the set-up of the document you work with.

Comment: Hello! so basically the context is that a prof of mine wants me to type out his handwritten notes into Latex. I have been working in Latex for a bit. But I have not written a document of this size (multiple chapters and stuff) so I would like to know how to make this process efficient and hence such a broad question. I don't have anything in mind just general advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having started with Latex myself about 18 months ago, I get your question. Please find some hints and guidelines below. You certainly raise a typical kind of question for many beginners, and can’t do “better” from the perspective of a seasoned Latex-user in this community.

Latex is not difficult, it’s only complex. Eat this elephant problem by problem. Here we go.

### Texmaker + MikTex

This editor and package management system work fine for me. The editor has some nice features. E.g. it can help you better see structures once your document grows. E.g. you can add to the autocompletion feature the way you want it to be.

I configured MikTex so it will ask me every time it wants to install a missing package. There will be plenty along your path.

### General strategy

- use standard first
- refine as needed AND once confidence grows
- i.e. delay requests until then and focus

You can go a long way by just using the standard commands, i.e. ignore any layout related request for quite some time. Layout isn’t difficult, just … complex in the beginning. Sure you can change a font here and there, tweek indenting, litter a document with rulers and so on. I suggest to focus on transferring content first, and introduce layout related aspects step by step along the way.

### Wikibooks

Know the Latex standard. Often that’s all you need, and you can better understand, why and how people came up with other solutions. Tables are in this ball park.

A good online source is [Wikibooks about Latex](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX). It may be a good idea to obtain a (used) printed introductory book on Latex with similar content to have it in parallel.

### Modularity

- you probably want documentclass book
- input vs. include: [look up the difference](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Modular_Documents#input_vs_include)
- use folder structure: Latex will litter your space
- big doc + check docs

To me the book class seems to be more suitable for your purpose, compared to the article class.

Have a root directory for your book. Write the structure into it’s .tex file first, i.e. set up parts, chapters, sections etc. first. Create the same nested folder structure and replace your .tex with `\input` statements as needed.

It also allows you to do the following:

- have one main.tex, i.e. your book-class
- you can compile everything, when needed, including every folder+file
- you can have dedicated chapMain.tex which inputs just the relevant chapter-files
- then you have a smaller book-document, which can be useful e.g. for checking purposes.

### Stepwise refinement

Use this approach excessively. E.g.

- write a few chapters into your main.tex
- “outsource” them, literally to folders and `\input` statements
- run compiles to verify it’s as you wanted (fail now)

This way you can always tidy up crowded files the way you need. Preambles sooner or later can be a good target for at least one `\input` statement.

### ctan is your friend

- finding: use e.g. enter *ctan equation* into your search engine
- topics: e.g. follow the package hint (at the bottom of a package page)
- habit of quick scan
- crosscheck here

ctan provides quadrillions of packages. So develop a habit of scanning quickly through the package documentation. Many times there are similar packages available, see e.g. the topic classification at ctan.

Very developed packages tend to provide overwhelmig documentation. That’s a good time to return to this place and search a little for this package here. You’ll quickly see, what other people struggled with, what better alternatives may be and so on.

Equations, QA, exam, all these are packages worth exploring at ctan and here.

### Figures and tables

Figures can drive a beginner crazy, because it’s “standard” to put them into a float environment. That’s a nice feature, AND you’ll never know where it will end up. There are extra packages to control it better; the easist is to not-float it. That’s one of the “care for it later” topics.

```
\begin{figure}% floating figures
... % whatever you draw
\caption{}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}%floating environment for tables
    ... % table inside
\end{table}
```

You probably want to use these table-related packages:

- tabularx *(lifting some limitations of tabular)*
- booktabs *(for a nicer look & feel)*
- longtable *(as it says)*

For graphics look for the `graphicx` package, which lets you `\includegraphics{}` from images.

It’s fine to start even with scanned manual sketches and translate them later into `tikz`. Tikz is a very big and very cute elephant, wrt. its package documentation. Time spent there (later) is time well-spent.

### Macros

The `\newcommand` statement is great e.g. to:

- introduce abbreviations
- make typeset presentation more uniform and flexible.

It’s not difficult and you’ll soon wonder how you could do without. Again, consider “outsourcing” text to dedicated macros from time to time, see stepwise refinement.

### Git and similar

All Latex is plain text. Even tikz-drawings are. So for backup and version management of your many bits and pieces you may want to spend a few thoughts on how to back up and how to make version control work for you.

Image files, like .png or .jpg, can be included, but you can’t easilyy check for differences/changes automatically with git.

### TEX StackExchange is your specific friend

Once you encounter a specific problem, post it here:

- one question only per question
- code, which shows your attempts and struggle
- ready to copy and compile
- pruned from unnecssary code.

You’ll be amazed about this place, once you “feed” it’s inhabitants this way.